# AADSTS70001: Application is not supported for this API version

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application that will need to check if a user is member of a specific group in an Azure Active Directory. To achieve this I will use Microsoft Graph API, so I downloaded their example to try it out from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph/quick-start) and got it running fine.

My next step is to get it running with my own AppId, AppSecret and RedirectUri and this is where I get in trouble. In Azure I went to "App registrations" for the AAD and assured that the application was added. I opened the app and copied the "Application ID" for the AppId, created a key and used it as the AppSecret. I checked all the permissions and pressed "Grant Permissions" and added my URL to the Reply URLs. I also changed the Authority attribute from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0 to https://login.windows.net/xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com.

When I run the application and press "Sign in" I will come to the login screen correctly, but it will crash when I try to sign in. The crash occurs when running AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync in the code below:

```
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                        ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
                            appId, 
                            redirectUri,
                            new ClientCredential(appSecret),
                            new SessionTokenCache(signedInUserID, context.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase));
                        string[] scopes = graphScopes.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

                        AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(scopes, code);
                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
```

The error message I get in AuthenticationFailed looks like this:

AADSTS70001: Application 'xxxxxxxx-4f81-4508-8dcb-df5b94f2290f' is not supported for this API version. Trace ID: xxxxxxxx-d04c-4793-ad14-868810f00c00 Correlation ID: xxxxxxxx-ab83-4805-baea-8f590991ec0c Timestamp: 2017-06-13 10:43:08Z

Can someone explain to me what the error message means? Should I try a different version? I have tried with both Microsoft.Graph v1.3.0 / Microsoft.Graph.Core v1.4.0 and Microsoft.Graph v1.4.0 / Microsoft.Graph.Core v1.5.0.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use MSAL with the v1 endpoints. This is evident from using `ConfidentialClientApplication`. You need to use ADAL (Azure AD Authentication Library) instead. *Or register the app for v2 at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com.*

You can get ADAL from NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/

You can find a sample app using ADAL here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect

Your OnAuthorizationCodeReceived will need to look something like this:

```
    private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
    {
        var code = context.Code;

        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));

        // If you create the redirectUri this way, it will contain a trailing slash.  
        // Make sure you've registered the same exact Uri in the Azure Portal (including the slash).
        Uri uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));

        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, uri, credential, graphResourceId);
    }
```